# How to disable UIScrollView PanGestureRecognizer when scroll to the edge of bounds

Tags: uiscrollview, scroll, uigesturerecognizer, zooming, uipangesturerecognizer

I have an UIImageView in an UIScrollView,the imageView's size is 300 * 500,the scrollview bounds is 300 * 300.I set the contentSize 300*500 for scrollview.When i scroll left or right,that is ok,the UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer not work because of the width is equal between contentSize and bounds.

When I scroll up or down,even if scrollview's contentoffsetY is 0 or the max 200,the UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer has been recognized.I don't want the UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer to be recognized at the edge as the super view of the scrollview should handle it.

Hown can i do that?